# How to manage read / write buffers in a clients / server architecture

Tags: sockets, client-server

I would like to know how to manage read and write buffers in a many clients / one server architecture.

My server is **asynchronous**.

My exact questions are:

- Do I need to have one read buffer per client connected, or one for the server globally ? Why ? (to avoid data crushing if multiple clients write to the server simultaneously for example).
- Same question with write buffer.
- If my server wasn't asynchronous, would it change any of the answers ?

Thank you in advance for your responses,

Flo

Comment: Are you trying to implement something specific ? Your questions sound a bit generic. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: A game lobby, multiple clients will connect to the server, and a lot a writes from clients to the server may come at possible high rate.

Comment: Have you had a look at the available RPC Frameworks, like (for example) Apache Thrift, Apache Avro or Google Protocol Buffers? It may save you hours and answer all of your questions at the same time.

Comment: To make it clear to everybody (yes, I'm looking at you, K.): The question in the former comment is a rhetorical question, with the intention to give the OP a hint what he migh find useful. It is not a question which expects an answer but instead it is indeed an answer on itself and therefore could be posted as an answer. If you don't know the difference, you are free to ask a question, but not on SO, because this is would be offtopic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to have one read buffer per client connected, or one for the server globally?

One per client, because you will get partial reads, and you need to keep reading to assemble entire messages: you want all that data in one place, adjacent.

> Same question with write buffer.

One per client, because you can get short writes.

> If my server wasn't asynchronous, would it change any of the answers?

No.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But what do you mean when you say "short writes" ?

Comment: In non-blocking mode, and maybe async mode too, a write can return having not transferred all the data in the buffer.